# What locks the dpkg when installing packages on boot?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, dpkg

We have a system with a script that install a lot of `deb` files when the computer first boots up. We are having trouble because dpkg sometimes randomly blocks the install because something else is using it. What can that thing be?
We uninstall `unattended-upgrades` before starting the installs but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Have you reviewed your apt logs, dpkg logs, syslog, and journal for those times?

Comment: No, will do, I didn't know those told you what had the lock at the moment.